# using select2 plugin for dropdown

Tags: javascript

Hi I am new at using select 2 plugin
I have an select2 dropdown with an placeholder

```
<select id="active_media_videos">
<option></option>
</select>

$("#active_media_videos").select2({
   allowClear: true,
   placeholder: "Select a Store"
});
```

The dropdown is populated with using ajax. When I press my cancel button in my form I empty the dropdown

`$("#active_media_videos").select2().empty()`
and when I open the form again the placeholder is gone.

Is there a way to get the placeholder back again?

Comment: Try maybe with `$("#active_media_videos").select2("val", "")`?